# throw exception with root cause error in my spring crud operation project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Error: (throw exception with root cause error in my spring crud operation project)

```
Error: Nov 14, 2017 12:43:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path 


[/Spring4MVCAngularJSExampleLatest] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.websystique.springmvc.service.UserServiceImpl.saveUser(UserServiceImpl.java:56)
    at 
com.websystique.springmvc.controller.HelloWorldRestController.createUser(HelloWorldRestController.java:69)
```

(The money was paid in a lump sum at the end of the engagement. My kind master, at my request, granted me a lump sum in place of my annuity. I propose to pay a lump sum on condition that you withdraw the suit at once. This appropriation is not in a lump sum but by allotments or funds.)

Code:

```
JavaService Impl:


public void saveUser(User user) 
{


System.out.println(user.getAddress()+""+user.getId());//printing successfully

        // user.setId(1);
        ((UserDaoImpl) users).saveOrUpdate(user);// i got error here
         //ud.saveOrUpdate(user);   
    }
```

=================================================

UserService.java This is service class

```
public interface UserService {

    User findById(long id);

    User findByName(String name);

    void saveUser(User user);

    void updateUser(User user);

    void deleteUserById(long id);

    List<User> findAllUsers(); 

    void deleteAllUsers();

    public boolean isUserExist(User user);

}
```

========================================================

UserDaoImpl.java:(This is repository impl class)

```
public List<User> list() {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM user12";
        List<User> listContact = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new RowMapper<User>() {

            @Override
            public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                User aContact = new User();

                aContact.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                aContact.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
                aContact.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                aContact.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));

                System.out.println("ASADADADAS" + rs.getString("username"));
                return aContact;
            }

        });
```

=================================

HelloWorldRestController.java(This is controller class)

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.GET)

    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> listAllUsers() {
        List<User> users = userService.findAllUsers();
       /* if(users.isEmpty()){
            return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);//You many decide to return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
        }*/
        return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

=============================

UserDao.java (this is repository class)

```
public interface UserDao {

    public void saveOrUpdate(User user);

    public void delete(int id);

    public User get(long id);

    public List<User> list();

}
```

Comment: JavaService Impl:

public void saveUser(User user) {
  
  
System.out.println(user.getAddress()+""+user.getId());//printing successfully
  // user.setId(1);
  ((UserDaoImpl) users).saveOrUpdate(user);// i got error here
   //ud.saveOrUpdate(user); 
 }

Comment: Don't add comments. Instead update the question body.

Comment: See entire code have above and tell me your suggestions to solve that one

Answer (score 0):

In the service the `((UserDaoImpl) users)` is null. It means it was not injected properly.

The UserDaoImpl must be annotated with @Repository (or @Component) to be a spring bean. Also it should be in component scan package to let Spring find it and create a bean.

Comment: I have added to annotations to UserDaoImpl.java

Comment: "Also it should be in component scan package to let Spring find it and create a bean." What is this mean?

Comment: are you using xml configuration or annotations based?